# How to increment a counter and append the result to a string to return an object name?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to develop a web application that is a drumming primer at http://101drums.com/flam.html.
The lessons are displayed as JPG images and have accompanying audio tracks to play along with.
I want my next button to increment a counter to load the next lesson. The lesson title, score, and track are in object arrays called `lesson1("title","score" etc)`, `lesson2("title",etc)`. So I need to change the number at the end of lesson. I am trying this but it does not work. Can you help?

```
p = integer.valueOf(localStorage.lessonNGS);
p = p + 1;
n = string.valueOf(p);
localStorage.setItem("lessonNGS", n);
var lesson = "lesson" + localStorage.lessonNGS;
```

Comment: The title is supposed to describe the actual problem, not your experience when trying to solve it.

Comment: Try and explain what your question is about in the questions title. The current title does not tell anything to the reader, and most will skip reading the question.

Comment: Looked at your source. Do not use `eval` when building strings. `Uncaught ReferenceError: lessonundefined is not defined` is the error on your page.

Comment: Will amend question title. Thanks for the advice about eval. I had read this before, but it was the only way I seemed to be able to fill those strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`localStorage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) and `parseInt`.

```
var p = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lessonNGS'), 10) || 0;
++ p;
localStorage.setItem('lessonNGS', p);
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I don't know what the | |  0; is doing? Can you tell me or show me where to look.

Comment: it's a fallback. so if `localStorage.getItem('lessonNGS')` doesn't exist yet (`null` or `undefined`), it will fallback to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Two notes:

1. use `parseInt` to parse strings into ints
2. you don't need to convert to string, javascript can handle the conversion when storing to the `localStorage`, and also when concatenating the integer to the "lesson" string.

This code should work:

```
p = parseInt(localStorage.lessonNGS, 10);
p = p + 1;
localStorage.setItem("lessonNGS", p);
var lesson = "lesson" + localStorage.lessonNGS;
```

Comment: are you sure that `localStorage.lessonNGS` is accessible in all browsers? it works in chrome but I couldn't find anything about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

Comment: parseInt should always include a radix, e.g. parseInt(foo, 10).

Comment: @Louy - `localStorage` is part of HTML5, it should be available on all browsers that support it.

Comment: I meant `localStorage.lessonNGS` vs `localStorage.getItem('lessonNGS')`.

Comment: @djechlin - the `radix` parameter can be omitted, in this case Javascript will make some assumptions based on the contents of the string (e.g. if it starts with 0x, or with a zero, etc)

Comment: Strongly not recommended. Leads to unexpected and buggy behavior because of the assumptions made by the function.

Comment: @djechlin - you have a valid point, will update the answer. As a sidenote, for this situation the developer has the control over the stored data, so it's not that problematic.

Comment: You didn't ask the developer whether lesson numbers will always have a fixed number of digits, e.g. "08,09,10".